# Failed Activity not running

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory v2 Pipeline with a copy data activity.  If the activity fails a Lookup activity should be run.  Unfortunately the Lookup never runs.  Why doesn't it run on failure of the copy data activity?  How do I get this to work?

[image: Pipeline Copy Activity Fails, Nothing else runs]

I'm expecting the "Set load of file to failed" activity to run because the Load Zipped File to Import Destination" activity failed.  In fact in the output you can see the Status is "Failed" but no other activity is run.

Later I updated the Copy Activity to skip incompatible rows which caused the Copy data activity to succeed.  The expected number of rows loaded now doesn't match the total number of rows loaded, so the If Condition activity goes to the failure route.  Why would the Lookup run from the If Condition only triggering the failure Activity vs the Copy Data activity?

[image: Set load of file to failed works from only If condition]

Answer (score 1):

Activity dependencies are a logical AND. The lookup activity *Set load of file to failed* will only execute if **both** the Copy data activity **and** the If condition fail. It's not one or the other - it's both. I blogged about this [here](https://datasavvy.me/2018/10/02/data-factory-v2-activity-dependencies-are-a-logical-and/).

It's common to redesign this as: 
A. Use multiple failure activities. Instead of having the one set load of file to failed at the end, copy that activity and have the copy data activity link to the new one on failure. 
B. Create a parent pipeline and use an execute pipeline activity. Then add a single failure dependency from the execute pipeline activity to *Set load of file to failed* activity emphasized text.

Comment: The next run I changed the copy data activity to skip rows that couldn't be loaded, so the copy activity succeeded, but the if condition noticed the expected number of rows to load didn't match the number of rows loaded.  In this case only the if condition called the "Set load of file to failed" That activity was called and worked as expected.  I'll still try to decouple the "Set load of file to failed" activity and make a second copy of it, but this doesn't explain why this scenario works as expected.  I'll edit my question with this image also.